# matplotlib's axvspan converts marker colors in scatter plot but not in ordinary plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I recently noticed the following phenomen in matplotlib (using v1.3.1 with Python3.3):

Minimal code example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(5),5*[3],'o', color="r", label="plt.plot")
plt.scatter(range(5),5*[2], color="r", label='plt.scatter')

plt.axvspan(1.5,4.5, color='yellow', alpha=0.5)

ax=plt.gca()
ax.legend(loc=6)

plt.savefig('adjusted_colors.png')
```

yields a plot with partially adjusted marker colors -- sorry for being not able to show the plot here -- namely markers plotted using pyplot's `scatter`-function in the area spanned by `axvspan`. 
In contrast, color of markers plotted via pyplot's `plot`-function is not converted.

Any ideas about how to avoid marker color's adjustment in case `plt.scatter` is used for plotting, respectively, how to turn it on in case of using `plt.plot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the "colors are adjusted" is not because the color actually changes, but because the scatter result (which is a `PathCollection` object) is being viewed through a half-transparent colored rectangle that it is *underneath*.  The same doesn't happen to the result of plot (which is a `Line2D` object) because it lies *above* the rectangle.

Matplotlib uses an attribute called `zorder` when it displays artists in a figure (most everything that lives in a matplotlib plot is an [artist](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html)).  The defaults set the plot's zorder to 2, whereas the rectangle and the scatter both have a zorder of 1, and the rectangle defaults to existing "higher" (not sure exactly why, but it is what it is).  You can force the scatter points to lie above the rectangle by specifying the zorder keyword:

```
 plt.scatter(range(5),5*[2], color="r", label='plt.scatter', zorder=2)
```

Or, if you want the opposite, do the same to move the plot points below the rectangle:

```
plt.plot(range(5),5*[3],'o', color="r", label="plt.plot", zorder=0)
```

Comment: zorder <-> drawing order.  For things with the same z it ends up depending on the internal details of how the artists are kept track of and lines and patches are dealt with slightly differently.